# Poor mans concurrency, understanding the monad instance?

Tags: haskell, monads, continuations

I'm running through [this](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis552/11fa/lectures/concurrency.html) guide to implementing concurrency and I'm having trouble understanding this monad instance:

```
data Action m = Atom (m (Action m)) | Fork (Action m) (Action m) | Stop

newtype C m a = C {apply :: (a -> Action m) -> Action m}

instance Monad (C m ) where
 m >>= f         = C $ \k -> apply m(\a -> apply (f a) k) --?
 return x        = C $ \k -> k x
```

I understand the fundamental uses of continuation monads, but I'm struggling to decipher what's going on in this declaration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might help to see that a `C m a` is really just a computation -- over an abstract `Action m` type -- of an `a` expressed in continuation passing style `(a -> Action m) -> Action m`, so the data constructor `C` and the corresponding record selector `apply` are just syntactic fluff.  Rewriting without them and without an explicit monad instance, you get the following equivalent code.  (Note that the type `Cnt` here is *just* a continuation, not a continuation monad. The continuation monad in `Control.Monad.Trans.Cont` is more like my `CPS` type.)

```
type Cnt m a = (a -> Action m)   -- a continuation, not a Cont monad
type CPS m a = Cnt m a -> Action m
bind :: CPS m a -> (a -> CPS m b) -> CPS m b
cps_a `bind` a_to_cps_b = \cont_b -> cps_a (\a -> a_to_cps_b a cont_b)
```

or the slightly more verbose:

```
cps_a `bind` a_to_cps_b =
  \cont_b -> cps_a (\a -> let cps_b = a_to_cps_b a in cps_b cont_b)
```

How does this work?  Well, the part in parentheses has a free variable `cont_b` that's a `b`-continuation; but, *given this continuation*, it's just an `a`-continuation that uses `a_to_cps_b` to construct a `b`-computation (in CPS style) which is applied to the free `cont_b` continuation.  In a nutshell, the part in parentheses is the supplied `a_to_cps_b` wrapped up in an `a`-continuation.  To combine it with `cps_a`, we just apply `cps_a` to this `a`-continuation, and that represents the combination of the `a`-computation represented by `cps_a` with the map `a_to_cps_b` that yields a `b`-computation, all expressed in CPS with a free variable `b_cont`.  Abstracting over this free variable gives us the `CPS m b` that we need.

I *think* that might help make the whole thing easier to understand, and you can now go back to the original definition, recognizing that `\a -> apply (f a) k` is really an `a`-continuation version of `f :: a -> C m b` expressed in terms of a free variable `k` representing a `b`-continuation.  `apply m` can be used to apply the `a`-computation `m` to this `a`-continuation, and we're left with something that combines the `a`-computation `m` with the map `f` from an `a` to a `b`-computation, all expressed in terms of a free `b`-continuation named `k`, which we can lambda-abstract to construct the needed `b`-computation which the bind operator should return.